# HTTPS request via AJAX from HTTP page

Tags: ajax, https

Would there be any problems calling an HTTPS page (e.g. a credit card authorisation service i.e. WorldPay) from a standard HTTP page via AJAX?

I can't imagine why there would be a problem, the response would be an HTML page which I could then embed in a result pane or such like?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes this would be a Cross domain posting and would be blocked by the browser.

Comment: and the reason browsers do this is because if users see https:// in their address bar (along with the lock symbol or whatever depending on browser), they have a different expectation of security and privacy than if it is http://.  In fact, if I was at your site and I was asked for credit card verification on a page that was http://, I would leave (even if the form or ajax involved used https).  Even Verisign had a page set up this way once, but it is bad form...

Comment: Would it really be blocked though?   http://domscripting.com/blog/display/91

Not saying it's a good idea - I agree with ferocious - but just need to be prepared!

Comment: @Duncan: yes, its highly unlikely the hacks suggested in that article would be supported by a site like WorldPay.  The only sensible options are a secure server-to-server exchange or a framed form supplied directly from the payment site (ala the VISA verfication thing that is quite common these days).

Comment: I understand the Problem when requesting HTTP content in a HTTPS context, but the other way round i think it wouldn't pose a security problem.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the insecurity of requesting HTTPS from HTTP. Only thing I can think of is the potential for the requested URL to include non-SSL requests and not also be validated. So no workaround?

Answer (score 5):

Anthony is right, but what you could do is create a local page the AJAX calls and that communicates with the HTTPS service via cURL or something else and returns. That way everything is done locally according to Java script.

Comment: Of course, since (in this case) this would involve credit card details being sent across the network in the clear, you absolutely should not do this.