# Moving from one https page to another with a different certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, https, worldpay

Imagine a bog-standard Signup page, which captures some user info like Name, Address etc.
It has a Buy Now button on it, which transfers to a payment site (WorldPay).

Now, the requirement is that everything should be secure, so that means (and correct me if I'm wrong)

A) I need to get and install an SSL certificate on IIS.

B) I then need to make the Signup page secure (looking at exactly how to do this but if anyone wants to let me know that would be grand!)

So, presuming that the Signup page is now https under one certificate, is there any reason AT ALL that there should be a problem redirecting to WorldPay (which is under SSL but under a different certificate) ?

I can't imagine why, I'm not going to be doing this over AJAX or anything (see [HTTPS request via AJAX from HTTP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012777/https-request-via-ajax-from-http-page)), but sometimes these things can bite you!

Thanks
Duncan

Answer (score 1):

The only problem that I can forsee is that if you have a direct form POST from https://mysite.com/ to https://payment.net/ your users will most likely see a warning page (FF3.5 shows an "untrusted connection" in a similar scenario - it's there to deter phishing attacks).  One possible solution to this would be to submit the mysite.com form to the mysite.com domain, and then have a controller or some such thing there that would redirect the user to payment.net from that.  (You want to watch out that you aren't playing loosey-goosey with the user's private information by exposing it on a URL, however.)

My guess is that this question is something that your payment site needs to deal with quite frequently.  I'd suggest contacting them to find out if they have specific recommendations for handling SSL, warnings, and so on.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's a bit of a surprise to me I have to say.  I'd have thought that www.mysite.com was completely secured under one certificate, if I choose to go to www.payment.net which is under a different domain and certificate the main thing should be that it's secure.... so didn't think there would be a problem.  Will clear it with WorldPay but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem with redirecting from one domain to the next using the same protocal (https). However, sometimes virus software can detect this kind of redirection as "phishing", but you should be okay if WorldPay is a trustworthy source. Are you trying to pass user data to WorldPay, or just using WorldPay as your payment engine? I wouldn't start passing any user information through POST/GET vars when switching domains.

The answer to your sign up page is that you need to force https (ideally from code behind) so users can enter their account information with the SSL encryption and see that trusty lock icon ;).

EDIT: CODE EXAMPLE

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().StartsWith("http://"))
{
   Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
}
```

To get your certificate: In your IIS, go to your properties of the website record, click on the security tab, then server certificates. Complete the step by step process until to have a certificate request ready to send to certificate signing authority (GeoTrust, Verisign etc.) Once you get it back from them, your certificate request can be finished and your https will work.

Also, check that your SSL software is up to date with the latest updates. That should cover the requirements. However, I would contact WorldPay as well just to be sure you are adhering to standards.

Comment: I want to POST data to the WorldPay domain which I've already captured on my https form (e.g. address)

Comment: If I want to have only ONE page that is https, do I do this through IIS by right clicking on the page, going to File Security and then selecting Secure Communications, or am I a bit off?  Also, on the ensure programmatically bit, I think I'll use this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx

Comment: You still have to setup a certificate to work with your primary domain, so I would just setup the cerficate the website level instead of the individual page. In your page code, depending what server-side language you are working with, just check the current protocol of the page and if it's not https, change it to https. Or, create a https class that you can extend to your page on demand. Are you working with asp.net?

Comment: I am working with ASP.NET yes.  A 'send me the codez' example would be great, if only because this is something I'm not easily able to google, and I'm sure it would be straightforward!  I must be putting in the wrong search terms...

Comment: Check out the recent edit, but your other solution could work as well.