# How to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cors

I want to make HTTPS calls from an HTTP webpage. I hope to solve this problem with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. How can I use it?

Comment: Search before asking...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6120260/1626399

Comment: I have already tried it and didn't work.

Comment: The HTTPS server needs to send it's [access control _Allow-Origin_ and _Credentials_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control) headers which permit the origin of the ajax call.

Answer (score 10):

On the HTTPS page (that you are requesting from the HTTP page) set the header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com

You can do this in PHP with:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.requesting-page.com");
?>
```

Alternatively if that doesn't work, you could create a file on your HTTP server (where the request is coming from) that downloads and displays the contents, this can be done in PHP with:

```
<?php
    echo  file_get_contents("https://www.requested-page.com");
?>
```

I would not advise doing this as it requires extra bandwidth and isn't good practice, it should only be used if you can't do the first option. Furthermore, if a developer has set the access control to be restricted it's probably for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really. It's the browser preventing it. Security reasons. You can look into cURL. Read this posting: [https-request-via-ajax-from-http-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012777/https-request-via-ajax-from-http-page)