# Cross Origin Resource Sharing - CORS

Tags: jquery, cors

Trying to make a cross origin call from one server to another server. Cant get it working. 
So made a test page with the code that works with this example 
http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/preflightInvocation.html

Here is my example page with same code:
http://webcosmo.com/test.html

However I am getting 403 forbidden error.

Anybody?

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? CORS isn't fully supported in IE<10, they either require a different xhr object or don't support it at all(IE6/7)

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but do you use any special headers? You may need to serve (e.g., for the Authorization header) an `Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization` CORS header allowing the client to send non-standard headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resource is missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Thus CORS won't work with it. Try adding this to your response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

[Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) for more info about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing on that. I need to have a response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to * or allowed domain back from server.

Comment: FWIW, and then after verifying that it works with `*`, for security, replace `*` with the domains which are permitted to access the resource! For example http://stackoverflow.com/a/16267287/199364

Answer (score 0):

if you add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` then your instruction `withCredentials` wont work.
The best practice is to add direct origin from request. 
In PHP you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];`

p.s.
also you can compare origins with your trusted domains and give limited access.