# How to send data between ajax and php in secure way?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, security

I have *index.php*, *ajax.js* and *process.php* (where I get my AJAX data).

I am using AJAX this way:

```
var = $('user_id').val();

$.ajax({
    url     : "somefile.php",
    method  : "GET",
    data    : {'user_id' : user_id},
    cache   : false,
    success : function(data) {
          // do something with "data"
    }
);
```

User_id I receive from PHP file:

```
    <input value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" id="user_id" />
```

What do I need to do for increasing security?

Comment: What aspect of security to do want to improve exactly - security against who? The user? Third parties?

Comment: This site is [replete with information](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=secure+ajax) about creating secure AJAX transactions. Do you have a specific problem not already covered?

Comment: I mean maybe like to encrypt sending data because it can be changed by someone while sending

Comment: Some useful info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012777/https-request-via-ajax-from-http-page

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r thanks for your notice. By the way it's my first question here and i agree with the fact that my question wasn't quite correct. Next time i'll be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Following can be added, just for increasing security measures,

In PHP code

```
<input value="<?php echo base64_encode($user_id); ?>" id="user_id" />
```

In JS Code:

```
var = $('user_id').val();

$.ajax({
    url     : "somefile.php",
    method  : "POST",
    data    : {'user_id' : user_id},
    cache   : false,
    success : function(data) {
          // do something with "data"
    }
);
```

In "somefile.php" 
for getting the file use the $_POST method, if will only accept the variable posted by using POST method. This can be used:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_id']))
{
$user_id=$_POST['user_id']
$user_id=base64_decode($user_id);
//all functionality here
} 
else
{
//shoot error message
}
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the security! Changing the encoding does not make anything more secure.

Comment: If you are sending sensitive data, HTTPS is a de facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you don't provide the userid to the client. Can you store it in a session variable instead?

Comment: I was thinking about that but the problem is that i also use anchor navigation so i open SECOND file it this INDEX.PHP and in this second php file i cant startsession(), it give errors :(

Answer (score 0):

If this user_id is being used to retrieve some confidential information related to the logged in user then that sounds like a security flaw.

You should be getting the user_id from a session variable

Answer (score 0):

I think is not an good idea to put 'user_id' in client HTML and send back to server. You need to do more validation with data that sent from client (do some checking and filtering).

I recommend to use session instead of sending it to client, But you will have problem if editing two or more data at same time (multi tab), So  you need to use session and some trick.

With this example your real `user_id` will never sent to the client.

**index.php:**

```
session_start();
$edit_session_id = md5(uniqid() . microtime(true));

$_SESSION['edit_' . $edit_session_id] = $user_id;
```

**ajax.js:**

```
var edit_session_id = $('#edit_session_id').val();

$.ajax({
    url     : "process.php",
    method  : "POST",
    data    : {'edit_session_id' : edit_session_id},
    cache   : false,
    success : function(data) {
          // do code
    }
);
```

**process.php:**

```
session_start();

$edit_session_id = $_POST['edit_session_id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['edit_' . $edit_session_id]))
{
    die('Invalid edit session, please go back & refresh');
}
$user_id    = $_SESSION['edit_' . $edit_session_id];

// Do something with user_id

//Clear the editing session
unset($_SESSION['edit_' . $edit_session_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use POST instead of GET and you should also use ssl so that yuor urls sart with https instead of http.Now you are secured enough but you can increase security by adding extra encryption layer.